# Relationship between magnetic force acted upon a diamagnetic substance and the magnetic field applied to it

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

I have a sample of bismuth that I have applied a measured B-field to through the use of a solenoid electromagnet. I've been trying to find a formula relating the B-field to the force that the bismuth would experience, but most of what comes up is based upon a charged particle, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Knowing the mass, resultant force, B-field applied, and the dimensions for the bismuth sample, how do I relate these factors with the magnetic permeability of bismuth?